# Frames per Second when drawing in Python

Tags: python

I am working on a project that involves drawing random pixels in a circle. I want to increase the rate in which the pixels are drawn. How do I change the frames per second. I looked at some examples but my code still does not work. I am using Python 3.2.3 and pygame 1.9 This is my code:

```
from pygame import*
from random import*

screen = display.set_mode((1000,800))
tick = time.Clock()
rand_spraypaint_xs = [] 
rand_spraypaint_ys = []
col1 = (0,0,0)
canvasRect = Rect(100,100,500,500)
tool = 'spraypaint'
draw.rect(screen,(0,255,0),canvasRect,0)
running = True
while running:
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False
    mx,my = mouse.get_pos()
    mb = mouse.get_pressed()
    x = randint(mx-30,mx+30)
    y = randint(my-30,my+30)
    dist =(((mx - x)**2 + (my - y)**2)**0.5)

    if dist <=30:
        rand_spraypaint_xs.append(x)
        rand_spraypaint_ys.append(y)
    if canvasRect.collidepoint(mx,my):
        if  tool == 'spraypaint':
            if mb[0]==1:
                screen.set_at((rand_spraypaint_xs[-1], rand_spraypaint_ys[-1]),col1)
                time.wait(1)
                tick.tick(10000)
    display.flip()
quit()
```

Comment: How are you drawing - PyGame, PyQt, PyOpenGL? Depending on the framework it could be very different?

Comment: Im drawing with pygame

Comment: I'd recommend putting a [Short Self Contained Correct Example](http://sscce.org) to give some more context to the code.

Comment: remove all instances of tick and fps as they will delay framerate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a for loop. If you set the for loop to be something like `for i in range(10)` it will perform the operation 10 times per frame:

For example:

```
    from random import*

screen = display.set_mode((1000,800))
tick = time.Clock()
col1 = (0,0,0)
canvasRect = Rect(100,100,500,500)
draw.rect(screen,(0,255,0),canvasRect,0)
running = True
while running:
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False
    mx,my = mouse.get_pos()
    mb = mouse.get_pressed()

    if mb[0]:
        for i in range(10): #8 can be changed to whatever value you want 
                            #to make it faster
            p = randint(0, 30), randint(0, 30)
            draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), p, 1)

    tick.tick(100)
    display.flip()
quit()
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could try only checking events ever 10 frames.:

```
count = 0
while running:
    if count >= 10:
        for e in event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                running = False
    else:
        count += 1
```